# Jquery Image Slider Back Bug

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Этот слидер слайдит до четвертой картинки, на 5 картинке аннулирует `margin-right: 0 ;`,
начинает слайдить заново. Проблема слайдить назад.

http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/ZYVrRY

Благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Устаревший слайдер, сейчас все современные решения используют `transform` для перемещения слайдов, что уменьшает нагрузку на процессор во много раз и работает плавнее. Если вопрос не входит в категорию "самообразовательных", я бы посоветовал готовое решение, к примеру, http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors